# Converting Integer to Time

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have an database that has a table which stores schedule information, including a clock in and clock out column. The problem is that whomever created this table made these to attributes as integers instead of time or datetime (This could also have been forced by the software that creates the schedule). So, for instance, instead of saying 8:00:00, it says 480 (the number of minutes that have passed that day). 18:00 (6 PM) shows 1080, Midnight is 1440, etc.

I have to query this for a report and do a calculation based off of the scheduled punches vs the actual hours worked which is stored as a time datatype. I am trying to convert the integer minutes into time of day in the select statement in order to have a CTE I can work with for multiple comparisons. So far this is what I've come up with (keep in mind the schedule is done by quarter hour increments, hence the .25, .5, .75, etc.)

```
SELECT CASE CAST(ClockIN AS decimal) / 60 
WHEN .25 THEN CAST('00:15:00.0000000' AS time)
WHEN .5  THEN CAST('00:30:00.0000000' AS time)
WHEN .75 THEN CAST('00:75:00.0000000' AS time)
WHEN  1  THEN CAST('01:00:00.0000000' AS time)
.....
WHEN  24 THEN CAST('00:00:00.0000000' AS time)
END AS ClockIn
```

I am trying to have clean code and not do too many calculations that take up resources every time the report is ran. Is there an easier way to do all of this, am I not thinking out of the box enough? So far this is the only way I can think of to accomplish what I need, which is an integer representing passed time converted to a timestamp Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a time and then use DATEADD to just add minutes to the time. So at 480 minutes, you'd add it to the new time created "00:00" and it should leave you at 8:00 AM.

```
DATEADD(minute, ClockIN, '00:00')
```

Comment: So there isn't any reason I couldn't use another column that stores the schedule date inside there, for instance: 
    DATEADD(minute, ClockIN, SchdDate). 
The hurdle I have with this, though, would be midnight records the next day's date as our schedule days run from 00:01 am to 12:00 am the following day. I guess I can always do a case that checks for midnight and if it is midnight, records the date and if not then does the above conversion. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use a real time instead of just 00:00. Good luck!